# How can you put your search information in the head?

Tags: html, tags, head

I know there is a way of putting search information in the head of HTML files, but I just don't know how exactly you can go about doing that. I believe they're called search tags and can help a browser to find your website but I just can't do it. If anyone could help with this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: They're called "meta tags" and they are obsolete for affecting search rankings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />    
        <meta name="keywords" content="" /> 
        <meta name="DC.Subject" content="" />
        <meta name="dc.language" CONTENT="en"/>
        <meta name="dc.source" CONTENT="http://www.???.org/"/>
        <meta name="dc.title" CONTENT=""/>
        <meta name="dc.keywords" CONTENT=""/>
        <meta name="dc.subject" CONTENT=""/>
        <meta name="dc.description" CONTENT=""/>
```